# Кастомный EventHandler

Tags: c#, .net

Есть `TypeDescriptor`. У него есть функция `GetProperties(object)`

Итак, беру коллекцию дескрипторов свойств и хочу добавить к некоторым обработчик на изменение.

```
var props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(someClassObject);
props[nameof(someClassObject.SomeProperty)].AddValueChanged(someClassObject, SomeHandler);
```

Вот тут `SomeHandler` должен иметь тип `EventHandler`. Но обычный ИвентХандлер не имеет параметров, а мне нужно передать в него, например, имя свойства, значение которого изменилось. Не могу сообразить как. По идее возможность должна быть. Просто по логике. Иначе зачем вообще дана возможность таким образом подписаться на изменение конкретного свойства, если нельзя узнать имя измененного свойства?

Comment: "обычный ИвентХандлер не имеет параметров" разве не имеет? а как же `object sender, EventArgs e` ?

Comment: @3per и что я могу передать в EventArgs? ))

Comment: экземпляр любого класса наследуемый от EventArgs с любимыми нужными вам свойствами

Comment: @3per, у меня почему то не получилось этого сделать

Comment: добавьте  код, где не получилось

Comment: @3per да нет уже того кода... Я временно запилил лямбду вида `(o, e) => { DoanythingWithMyParams(); }`

Comment: @3per если есть возможность, попробуйте и оформите в ответ. Ну или я сам еще раз попробую позже

Comment: если не нравится обычный `EventHandler`, попробуйте `EventHandler<T>` или сами объявите тип делегата с нужной сигнатурой.

Comment: @rdorn, я не могу ничего объявить... прочитайте вопрос еще раз. Требуется именно `EventHandler`

Comment: что в `sender` передается? проверить сам смогу только вечером. и какой тип у параметра `e` на самом деле, после вызова обработчика?

Comment: @rdorn, я понятия не имею.

Comment: а посмотреть? повесить обработчик который будет выводить тип `sender` и `e` , в консоль или `MessageBox`. ну или просто бряк в обработчике поставить и в режиме отладки посмотреть текущие значения. У видите реальные типы параметров, от этого уже плясать будем

Comment: @rdorn если честно я пока не могу смоделировать ситуацию при которой срабатывает данный хандлер :)

Comment: подозреваю, что его должно вызывать свойство, когда у него меняется значение, а если свойство этого не умеет, то и вызывать будет некому. Если это так, то мой предыдущий ответ более чем актуален, передаете производный EventArgs во время активации события

Comment: @rdom, да, я так и думал. Так написано на MSDN, но фактически при изменении свойства ничего не срабатывает... пока разбираюсь почему

Comment: @rdorn, и как собираетесь передавать свой класс производный от EventArgs? Если только, конечно, автор вопроса не пишет свой компонент.

Comment: @iRumba, особо не разбирался, но, вроде бы, если компонент реализует интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged, то тогда параметр e будет объектом класса PropertyChangedEventArgs, у которого есть свойство PropertyName. А так больше никак нельзя, только с помощью замыкания.

Comment: @nuts119 так я об этом и писал, возможно не очень понятно получилось. Ночью лучше пишется, мысли не разбегаются %)

Comment: @rdorn, а, ну значит я не догнал сразу)

Comment: @rdorn в этот хандлер приходит именно EventArgs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы это работало, класс исследуемого объекта должен реализовать интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`, и исследуемое свойство должно инициировать событие при изменениях.

Небольшой демонстрационный пример для понимания:

```
class Program : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }

    private int _prop2

    public int Prop2
    {
        get { return _prop2; }
        set { _prop2 = value; OnPropertyChanged("Prop2"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    private static void P_PropertyChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.GetType().ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(sender.GetType().ToString());
        if (e is PropertyChangedEventArgs)
        {
            var realArgs = (PropertyChangedEventArgs)e;
            Console.WriteLine(realArgs.PropertyName);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();

        var props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(p);
        props[nameof(p.Prop1)].AddValueChanged(p, P_PropertyChanged);
        props[nameof(p.Prop2)].AddValueChanged(p, P_PropertyChanged);

        p.Prop1 = 1;
        p.Prop2 = 2;
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Если запустить и посмотреть вывод программы, то легко заметить, что для свойства `Prop1` обработчик не вызывается, т.к. это свойство не уведомляет об изменениях. Для свойства `Prop2` при изменении обработчик вызывается, т.к. мы заранее позаботились о том, чтобы свойство уведомляло об изменениях и в обработчик передается не пустой `EventArgs`, а `PropertyChangedEventArgs` который и содержит имя свойства.

Вот только остается вопрос: зачем такие сложности, если можно сразу подписаться на событие `PropertyChanged`, которое определено в интерфейсе `INotifyPropertyChanged` без которого все это, вообще говоря бесполезно? Проверить что класс реализует интерфейс и подписаться напрямую на событие без посредников мне кажется гораздо легче и понятнее.

Comment: Вы вопрос внимательно прочитали? Как я в хандлер этот передам `SomeEventArgs`?

Comment: Посмотрите на кусочек кода... там в конце есть `SomeHandler`. Это тот самый хандлер. Как мне передать с ним `SomeEventArgs`?

Comment: получилось немного дольше чем рассчитывал, но зато с рабочей демкой

Comment: Ну в таком случае не нужны такие сложности. Я то хотел каким то магическим образом подписаться на изменение свойства, которое само не оповещает о своем изменении.